# Finding it hard to do a chart in excel

Tags: excel, templates, graph, charts

I am interested in plotting an excel graph exactly like in the image I am pasting here.

[image: The Chart I am trying for]

It has been obtained from tables arranged like this

[image: Excel sheet]

The table has been arranged in excel.. However try as I may I am not able to put my data (arranged in the same manner in excel) into a similar graph/chart. Has anybody previously worked with a chart template like this? If so, please direct me to it. When i put 2 values in a single cell with the colon separating them, the charts I plot are not even eble to recognize the number before the colon as a single value and the number after the colon as a single value. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel charts plot sets of single numbers. 123;456 is not a single number.

What do the members of each pair signify?

Here's one way to approach your problem:
Keep the range containing the ;-separated values. This range will be for display.
Create another range that has two columns for every :-separated value, and split these into separate values. This range will be data for the chart.
Note that you'll need both X and Y values for the points you plot, and plotting a vertical line for each point requires a little finagling.